# "mov ds, ax" shows 0xC0000005 error in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

I'm using Visual Studio to build a console program, and I've used inline assembly instructions in this C program as shown in the picture: [code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E6pz.jpg).
For those who can't see the picture, the code I've written is:

```
void main() {
    __asm {
        mov ax, 0x4;
        mov ds, ax; // 0xC0000005 error occurs while executing this instruction
        xor eax, eax;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am tring to assign a value to the DS segment register, and I've used AX to transfer the value to the DS register(so I'm not directly assigning the value to the DS register).

The compilation and linking are both OK, but when I debug this program, I get the error code: 0xC0000005. Running without debugging resulting the same error.

I'm using Chinese version of Visual Studio, and I'm not sure what's the exact translation of this error message, but it's rough meaning shoule be:
"**There is an unhandled exception at 0x008e13c2: 0xC0000005: access conflict occured while reading 0xffffffff.**"

Q1: Is any one knows why this is happening? Can't I assign a random value to the DS register?

By the way, another question is, when I assign number 0 to 3 to the DS register, no error occured, but the register window on the bottom left corner of Visual Studio shows that **the DS register's value hasn't been changed**.

Q2: Why is this happening? Have I successfully assigned value to the DS register or not?

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Because the code generated by the compiler is probably using `ds` for something else? If you want to do DOS-level programming use an actual assembler that targets DOS, and use an emulated environment to run the program.

Comment: 04h is not a valid selector as it index the descriptor 0 within the LDT with RPL = 0 (which you cannot use having CPL = 3 and being the null descriptor reserved)

Comment: You cannot fumble around with the DS register. What are your trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm new to assmbly language, I've seen some examples of moving values to `ds`, so I just assume that I can assign any value to ds. I use visual studio just because I'm more familiar with this IDE and C programing language.

Comment: Because it CPU is running in protected mode. If you want to learn assembly, either use an 8086 emulator (real mode emulator) or switch to an easier assembly language like M68K or MIPS.

Comment: Or switch to 32b (protected mode) x86 examples, where you will NOT see moving values into `ds` (most of the time).

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio runs under Windows, Windows switches the CPU into [protected mode (PM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode).
In PM you can no longer assign the selector registers, like `ds`, any value you want ,rather the OS loads those registers for you.

Assuming the OS is not flawed in this aspect, and Windows is not, any other value<sup>1</sup> (but for those on the other selector registers) will trigger an exception.

---

If you have seen code like

```
mov ax, cs
mov ds, ax

mov ax, 0b800h
mov es, ax

mov ax, ...
mov ds, ax
```

Then it's [real mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode) code and it is not suitable to run under Windows anymore<sup>2</sup>.
You may want to consider using a DOS emulator (like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)) and an assembler/compiler that can generate 16 bit executables (like [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/), [MASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler), [TASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Assembler) or Turbo C).

---

The values 00h - 03h are special in this aspect as they all represent the *NULL selector* and

> A NULL segment selector (values 0000-0003) can be loaded into the DS, ES, FS, and GS registers without causing
>   a protection exception. However, any subsequent attempt to reference a segment whose corresponding segment
>   register is loaded with a NULL value causes a general protection exception (#GP) and no memory reference occurs.

The value 04h doesn't refer to NULL descriptor and the exception is raised as soon as you try to set `ds` with it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually the OS may create other descriptors accessible to user space program, but with the assumption made their use would be equivalent to the one already present in the registers. Hence there is no point in changing those.

<sup>2</sup> Actually 32-bit versions of Windows support 16-bit programs, but, since Vista, 64-bit versions don't. Visual Studio cannot generate MZ exes anyway, as per @RossRidge comment, you'll need Visual C++ 1.5 or previous.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks! Correction in progress!